# Matlab plotting only every Xth point

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm wondering if it is possible to plot only every Xth point in a Matlab `plot`.

I have a long list of points where I only want to display a subset of (due to the huge amount).

My points are from the styl:

```
ONE = [x1,y1 ; x2,y2 ; x3,y3 ; x4,y4 ; x5,y5 ; ...];
TWO = [x'1,y'1 ; x'2,y'2 ; x'3,y'3 ; x'4,y'4 ; x'5,y'5 ; ...];
```

what I'm currently doing is the following:

```
figure;
plot([ONE(:,1) TWO(:,1)].',[ONE(:,2) TWO(:,2)].','g', ONE(:,1),ONE(:,2),'bx',TWO(:,1),TWO(:,2),'ro')
hold off
drawnow
```

which plots me all points from `ONE` in blue `x` and all points from `TWO` in red `o`. These points are connected with a green line (`[x1,y1]` with `[x'1,y'1]`, ...). This works all great, but due to the amount and the points its a bit overloaded. Therfore I just want to display a couple of points.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index the points you want to plot:

```
1:k:end
```

where k indicates the stepsize

e.g. for every 4 points use

```
plot(ONE(1:4:end,1), ONE(1:4:end,2))
```